# No scl command after installing Software Collections

Tags: command, installation, centos7, yum

I have CentOS 7 and after having installed the Software Collections (SCL) I do not find any `scl` command:

```
$ yum install centos-release-scl
$ which scl
/usr/bin/which: no scl in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:/root/bin)
```

Does anybody know how to "see" such command?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18):

This error message is usually caused when you do not have `scl-utils` installed.
Try doing

```
yum install scl-utils
```